# When to flash in TextureView camera

Tags: java, android, camera, textureview

I have a fragment for a custom camera on my application, and I am trying to implement a flash on/off button for my camera.

Right now I have something like this:

```
private Camera camera;
private Camera.Parameters params;
private boolean flash;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    // Flash on/off button click;
    final ImageButton buttonTurnFlash = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_turn_flash);
    buttonTurnFlash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { turnFlash(); }
    });
}

private void turnFlash() {
    if (flash) flash = false;
    else flash = true;
}
```

And then I call this method when the user click the "Take photo" button:

```
private void takePicture() {
    try {
        if (flash) {
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
        }

        final Bitmap bitmap = textureView.getBitmap();
        final FileOutputStream fos = Controller.getContext().openFileOutput("image.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

If the flash is off, I get a really nice picture. However if I turn the flash on, and try to take a picture, the flash blinks indeed, but the result is a photo without flash, just like the flash was off.

I'm pretty newbie on camera stuff, but I'm pretty sure that when the flash blinks and then call the method ***getBitmap()***, the moment he gets the bitmap, the flash is already gone or already blinked. Is there any way to delay the flash until the ***getBitmap()*** method is complete? What is the best aproach for this?

Answer (score 0):

To take photo with flash mode use `params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)`

Comment: And where should I set the params? I tried to set FLASH_MODE_ON just before the getBitmap(), and this time the flash didn't even blink. Should I put the params in other place?

Comment: So first set FLASH_MODE_TORCH for 2 second and then set FLASH_MODE_ON

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean flashmode = false;


    // check the flash is available or not by writing this code in onCreate

        if (!getBaseContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                buttonTurnFlash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

and call the flashOnButton() method in ur onClick of the button.

```
 private void flashOnButton() {
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
                param.setFlashMode(!flashmode ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH
                        : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(param);
                flashmode = !flashmode;
            } catch (Exception e) {
               `enter code here` // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
```